# Cant click anything on Android Studio unless I open it by root

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, centos, root

Good day,

I have CentOs Linux, and I have install Android Studio on it.

I open the Android Studio 4.0 by terminal, I cd to /opt/android-studio/bin, and run ./studio.sh

The Android Studio software will launch, but I cant click anything on it:
[image]

Also I cant close it by click on the "X" icon, or ctrl c in the terminal. I need to open another terminal, use `ps -ef | grep Android` to find its Id to kill it.

Unless I logged in as root, and run the same command, then I only can launch the Android Studio and able to click on it, but it will show that this Android Studio is run by root. I need to configure the Android SDK to download the latest Android SDK Build-Tools, but not sure will give any impact or not.

[image]

As you can see, the UI interface color also different, anyone know what is happening?

Comment: i'm not saying your question is off-topic, but you might find better answers posting over at a linux community as well

Comment: @a_local_nobody , can suggest me the community forum?

Comment: honestly no idea, i'm just thinking that it might be a linux specific issue so people might know more about it on a linux community

Comment: @a_local_nobody, I think I found it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: just make sure you read the community guidelines before posting, just to be sure that your question belongs there :) this is all just a suggestion i'm making